# Solving $V_t=V_{xx}$ on $\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb{R}\}, t>0$ and $V(x,t)=e^tf(x)$ for some function $f$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Find solutions to $V_t=V_{xx}$ on $\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb{R}\}, t>0$ and $V(x,t)=e^tf(x)$ for some function $f$.

So I have that $V_{xx}(x,t)=e^tf''(x)$ and $V_t(x,t)=e^tf(x)$

But from the equation I get $e^tf''(x)=e^tf(x)$?

So I should have $f''(x)=f(x)$?

I'm not really sure what to be doing from here, or if what I've done even makes sense.

But solving $y''-y=0$
I get $r^2-r=r(r-1)=0$
So I have $r=0,r=1$
So $f(x)=c_1e^{x}+c_2$ is a solution?

But this doesn't seem to work with me given equations. Since if $V(x,t)=c_1e^te^x+c_2e^t$

then $V_t=c_1e^te^x+c_2e^t\neq V_{xx}$

Comment: This is the heat equation, are you familiar with it?

Comment: @K.defaoite Other then it just being the equation of the form $V_t=V_{xx}$, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake when writing out the characteristic polynomial of $y''-y=0$.
The correct polynomial is $r^2 -1$. Otherwise what you have done is correct.

Answer (score 1):

So l take it that we are asked for solutions of

$V_t = V_{xx} \tag 1$

on the set

$\Omega = \{ (x, t): x \in \Bbb R, 0 < t \in \Bbb R \} \tag 2$

which take the form

$V(x, t) = e^tf(x), \tag 3$

where

$f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \tag 4$

is sufficiently differentiable.  How differentiable?  Well, it is implicitly indicated that

$V_{xx} = (e^t f(x))_{xx} = e^t f''(x) \tag 5$

exists, hence

$f(x) \in C^2(\Bbb R, \Bbb R). \tag 6$

Now it follows from (3) that

$V_t = e^tf(x), \tag 7$

and this in concert with (1) and (5) yields

$e^t f''(x) = e^tf(x), \tag 8$

whence, since

$e^t \ne 0, \tag 9$

we have

$f''(x) = f(x), \tag{10}$

which of course may be solved in the usual fashion: setting

$f(x) = e^{rx}, \tag{11}$

it is easy to see that

$f'(x) = re^{rx}, \tag{12}$

$f''(x) = r^2e^{rx}, \tag{13}$

and thus *via* (10), (11), and (13),

$r^2e^{rx} = e^{rx}, \tag{14}$

from which, dividing by $e^{rx} \ne 0$,

$r^2 = 1, \tag{15}$

that is,

$r = \pm 1. \tag{16}$

We conclude that $e^{\pm x}$ are two linearly independent solutions of (10), and since (10) is a second order equation, these two functions span its entire space of solutions.  Thus we may write

$f(x) = c_+ e^x + c_-e^{-x}; \tag{17}$

now combining (3) and (17) we find that

$V(x, t) = e^t(c_+ e^x + c_-e^{-x}), \tag{18}$

the requisite result.  Note that we have also shown that

$f(x) \in C^\infty(\Bbb R, \Bbb R) \tag{19}$

in the course of the derivation of (18).